# Xamarin cross platform UWP images are missing

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, uwp

I am working on Xamarin cross platform project where if I placed the images inside the sub folder it is not loading on the screen.

Please refer my code and folder structure along with properties

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put your Images folder under Assets Folder like this:

```
Assets/Images/*.png
```

and if you are using Localizing make like this:

```
Assets/Images/en/*.png
Assets/Images/another language/*.png
```

for more information you can check this [Working with Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)
i hope that answer you question.