# Info button on the right side of the Xamarin.Forms TitleView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Android/iOS/UWP Xamarin.Forms app. At the top of the screen where the TitleView is I want to place a button that leads the user to a page that shows them more information about my app.

I tried:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="My App" FontSize="Large"></Label>

        <Image x:Name="info" 
               Source="information.png"  
               WidthRequest="20"  
               HeightRequest="20" 
           />
    </StackLayout>

</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

On UWP this result in the title of the app being shown in addition to *MyApp* in the TitleView. However in Android, once I add a custom TitleView, the title of the app isn't shown anymore. How do I get uniform behavior where the title text shows once on both platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is different between Android and UWP. In Android and iOS, if you custom the title view of navigation bar, the title will no long appear.

1. You can use `OnPlatform` as Evgeniy Stepanov mentioned to add additional titleLabel to show the title in iOS and Android.
2. You can simplily add a `ToolbarItem` to place the Info button on the right side of the navigationbar:

   ```
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       Title = "My App";

       ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("", "info", () => { goToInfoPage(); }, ToolbarItemOrder.Primary, 1));
   }

   public void goToInfoPage() {

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you added "information.png" image to android resources? [Check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850510/how-to-correctly-use-the-image-source-property-with-xamarin-forms)
2. Try to use OnPlatform

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="My App" FontSize="Large"/>
        <Image x:Name="info" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20">
            <Image.Source>
                <OnPlatform UWP="logo.png" Default="logo" x:DataType="ImageSource"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
```