# how to display an image on xamarin forms using binding tag from image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using xamarin forms trying to display an image using binding...followed a few online Q's already including the answer on this one `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850510/how-to-correctly-use-the-image-source-property-with-xamarin-forms` just cant seem to get the image to display...yes I knoW I can load the image by using  `<Image Source="Bud.jpeg"></Image>` which works fine....but I would like to display it using binding....

eg..

```
xaml
 <Image Source="{Binding imageTest}"></Image>


code

            var imageTest = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
            imageTest.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("Guinness.jpg");
```

anyone any idea why? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind to public properties

```
<Image Source="{Binding imageTest}" />
```

then declare a public property in your code-behind

```
public string imageTest { get; set; }
```

and then set the property value and `BindingContext`

```
imageTest = "Guinness.jpg";
this.BindingContext = this;
```