# Add image into treeview control xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

First xamarin app...testing the android...looking at the treeview example on https://github.com/danvanderboom/Xamarin-Forms-TreeView

Would like to include an image through binding into the treeview node...
Ive got the image displaying through binding from 
[how to display an image on xamarin forms using binding tag from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111933/how-to-display-an-image-on-xamarin-forms-using-binding-tag-from-image)
its when I try to include it in the treeview where it isnt working....so far

so looking at HighEnergy.TreeView.Demo(Portable) -> Demo Module folder.

In DemoTreeNode.cs I have added

```
string _ImagePath = string.Empty;
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return _ImagePath; }
        set { Set("Image", ref _ImagePath, value); }
    }
```

in DemoTreeViewModel had edited the tree node to include image...

```
MyTree = new DemoTreeNode { Title = "Root", ImagePath= "champagne.jpg", Score = 0.5, IsExpanded = true };
```

In DemoTreeCardView.xaml I have included the image tag just after the title:

```
<Label x:Name="TitleLabel" Text="{Binding Title}" Font="Bold,20" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
```

then in the DemoTreeCardView code behind I have included the bindingContext()

```
    namespace HighEnergy.TreeView.Demo
{
    public partial class DemoTreeCardView : ContentView
    {
        public DemoTreeCardView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

The image champagne.jpg is located in the Andriod project -> Resources -> drawable -> champagne.jpg and is set to andriodResource for build action

any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to add image control in DemoTreeCardView, then using binding to display image in HighEnergy.Controls.TreeView? Am I right? If yes, I suggest you can set Image control width and height, now, you can see the image display.

Here is the DemoTreeCardView, setting Image control width and height.

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#CCCCCC" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <!-- left side -->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <ContentView WidthRequest="30"/>

            <!-- tree node indentation spacer -->
    <BoxView x:Name="Spacer" WidthRequest="{Binding IndentWidth}"/>

            <!---this is a very bad way to load images, very slow, need to cache them somehow -->
```

-->

```
            <Label x:Name="TitleLabel" Text="{Binding Title}" Font="Bold,20" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding Imagepath}" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- right side -->
        <!-- if you're testing on a smaller (smartphone) screen, you can comment out the following right side of content and delete one of the ColumnDefinitions for the Grid-->
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="16,0,0,0">
            <Label Text="{Binding Score,StringFormat='{0:F3}'}" Font="16" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <!-- TODO: bind WidthRequest and use ValueConverter to convert from 0-1 score to the width of the chart on screen -->
            <ContentView BackgroundColor="Green" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#00000000" Command="{Binding ToggleIsExpandedCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

In the DemoTreeNode class, add ImagePath property.

```
 string _Imagepath = string.Empty;
    public string Imagepath
    {
        get { return _Imagepath; }
        set { Set("Imagepath", ref _Imagepath, value); }
    }
```

In the DemoTreeViewModel class, set Imagepath value.

```
public DemoTreeViewModel()
    {
        MyTree = new DemoTreeNode { Title = "Root", Score = 0.5, IsExpanded = true };

        var a = MyTree.Children.Add(new DemoTreeNode { Title = "Branch A", Imagepath = "plu3.png", Score = 0.75, IsExpanded = true });
        a.Children.Add(new DemoTreeNode { Title = "Leaf A1",Imagepath="plu3.png", Score = 0.85, IsExpanded = true });
        a.Children.Add(new DemoTreeNode { Title = "Leaf A2", Imagepath = "plu3.png", Score = 0.65, IsExpanded = true });

        var b = MyTree.Children.Add(new DemoTreeNode { Title = "Branch B", Imagepath = "plu3.png", Score = 0.25, IsExpanded = true });
        b.Children.Add(new DemoTreeNode { Title = "Leaf B1", Imagepath = "plu3.png", Score = 0.35, IsExpanded = true });
        b.Children.Add(new DemoTreeNode { Title = "Leaf B2", Imagepath = "plu3.png", Score = 0.15, IsExpanded = true });


    }
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @John, If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Brilliant...thanks for your help Cherry...Much appreciated!